# Python IDLE not accepting quotes

Tags: python, keyboard, python-idle

Disclaimer: I'm a noob.

I've installed Python 3.2 (r32:88452) and ActiveTcl 8.5.9.2 (build 294317) on my OSX 10.6. Both installed without any errors, and I've already managed to run a .PY through Terminal. It runs okay.

I run IDLE and it doesn't show any errors. But whenever I press the quote key ('), nothing happens. The same with [shift] pressed ("). The characters just don't register. The same happens with the 'backtick'/tilde key, [shift] pressed or otherwise.

I'm using a U.S. International keyboard layout.

I've tried opening the Keyboard Viewer. Both keys, single quote and 'backtick', are orange-colored. (I had never noticed that until now.) In any other application, whenever they're clicked, the corresponding character is input -- but nothing happens from within the Python IDLE.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

*Additional information: Python interpreter in interactive mode (running it from Terminal) registers both keys just fine. Also, if I try and change the keyboard layout to plain "U.S.", even IDLE registers the keys; but this tastes more like a workaround and I'd like to hear your opinions.*

Comment: Does this happen in other Tk/TkInter apps?

Comment: Please bear with me: I'm learning Python and I don't know exactly what Tk/Tkinter are. But I tried `from Tkinter import *` from IDLE and this is what I got: `>>> from Tkinter import *  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named Tkinter`

Comment: Bleh. This is not related to the actual problem. It seems that in Python 3.1+, "Tkinter" is named "tkinter".

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem with IDLE, but you could try IPython: http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/FrontPage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDLE uses `Tkinter` from  the Python standard library to supply GUI functionality. Tkinter is an interface to the multi-platform `Tk` graphical interface, part of `Tcl/Tk`.  Unfortunately, Aqua `Tk` on OS X does not currently support all of the standard text processing features on OS X.

This particular problem appears to be  a variation of a known bug in the Cocoa Aqua Tk.  On a normal Apple U.S. keyboard, you use `option U` + `<vowel>` to form a diaeresis (for example, `ä`).  It looks like on the US International keyboard, the `'` key is used instead of the missing `option u`.  There is a patch in the most recent ActiveState Tk 8.5 versions (including the one you have installed) that prevents Tk from crashing in this case.  You can see how it used to "work" by launching the Apple-supplied IDLE 2.6 included with Mac OS X 10.6 (`/usr/bin/idle2.6`).  Try typing `'` (with the International keyboard setting) or `option U` (with the US keyboard setting) there!  The patched version simply ignores this case, rather than crashing.

Your best bet is to stick to a `US` or `US Extended` keyboard input method.

Comment: I see. Thanks for reminding me of the U.S. keyboard layout method for accented characters. I'll try and file it up as a bug.  Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: See the updated reply and http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2907388&group_id=12997&atid=112997

Answer (score 0):

Changing to "plain US" is not a workaround but a solution for you, unless you really want to stick with U.S. International layout for some reason. Here are [some guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#US-International) on US International Layout.

Comment: I swear I'm not (deliberately, at least) trolling, but I don't think this should be the IDLE's default behavior. Shouldn't it correctly identify my keyboard layout and what my keyboard keypresses mean?

Comment: Yes, it should. How does it behave on say applications like Notepad when you try do do a `"` or `'`? Or as Ignacio asks, on another Tkinter app. (If you are on windows, you can find some Tkinter apps in Python directory. Scripts or Tools)

Comment: Both keys behave as expected: the first keypress registers as a "dead key" -- if then I input a vowel, any application outputs the accented character; if not, it outputs the quote/backtick/etc. I've chosen the U.S. International layout because I write mostly in portuguese (as I live in Brazil), and it would be somewhat bothersome if and when I'd have to use accented characters inside strings, for example. I'll try and find/test another Tkinter app.

Comment: I see your intention behind using this layout. Sorry that I thought it was by mistake. Please try on other tkinter apps and if you find the same problem, it may well be a bug, either in Tkinter classes or IDLE depending upon behavior you find in others.